# Sum of the size of all tags in SWF == SWF size specified in header?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, magic-numbers

I'm writing a SWF parser, and I'm currently stuck at this problem. [The header spec](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf) says that the size of the SWF is specified in the header itself (signature 3 bytes, version 1 byte, size 4 bytes...)

But then, if I iterate over each tag and get it's size, I end up with nearly the size that is specified in the header, but not that exact size.

Example:

```
sig:        FWS
version:    10
length:     3081
screen:     800.0x600.0
fps:        30.0
num frames: 1
4
458
4
3
26
853
1610
66
0
0
```

Each number printed after `num frames` is a tag's size. If I sum all of those, I get `3024`. The header itself is `1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 4 + X + 2 + 2`, being `X = 8` in this case (it's a variable length field). So that is `20`, added to the result of the sum of all tag's size, gives me `3044`.

Where are the `3081 - 3044 = 37 bytes` remaining bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it right, I just forgot to sum the bytes required to get the  size.

Example:

```
|header|tag 24 bytes|tag 37 bytes|tag 7364 bytes|tag 14 bytes|
```

So we have:

`SWF` (signature, 3 bytes)

+

`version` (1 byte)

+

`size` (4 bytes)

+

`rect` (let's say 9 bytes)

+

`frame rate` ( 2 bytes, first is ignored, but still counts for the total size)

+

`frame count` (2 bytes).

That gives us a total of `21` bytes for the header.

Then we start reading each tag block.

`tag type and length` (2 bytes)

+

(another 4 bytes if the tag length is equal to 63. This will happen only in the 3rd tag in this example)

+

(the actual size of the tag, `24` in this case)

**In this example, we'd have this:**

1. This tag's size is `2 + 24`
2. The next tag's size is `2 + 37`.
3. And the next one is `2 + 4 + 7364`.
4. The last one is `2 + 14`.

So the final size of the file is: `21` (header) + `26` (size of 2 byte field for type and length of tag + 24 of the actual tag) + `39` (2nd tag) + `7372` (3rd tag) + `16` (4th tag) = `7474`.

That number should match the number that you get from the header, when you read the 4 bytes field that contains the size.